# How to validate Enum String with Joi latest version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

How do I validate Enum String?

I used to go with this as suggested from here: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1449

```
enum UserRole {
  Admin = 'admin',
  Staff = 'staff'
}

const validator = {
  create: Joi.object().keys({
    first_name: Joi.string().min(1),
    last_name: Joi.string()
      .min(1)
      .required(),
    password: Joi.string()
      .regex(/^[\x20-\x7E]+$/)
      .min(8)
      .max(72)
      .required(),
    role: Joi.string()
      .valid([UserRole.Admin, UserRole.Staff])
      .optional(),
    is_active: Joi.boolean().optional()
  })
};
```

But now , `Error: Method no longer accepts array arguments: valid`

Comment: Well, it's in the [changelog](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/2037): *"No longer accepts array arguments. Must pass each value as a separate argument."* `.valid(UserRole.Admin, UserRole.Staff)`

Answer (score 16):

I could make it work using Joi.any().valid()  like this, hope works for you.

```
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

const roles = ["admin", "staff"];

const schema = Joi.object({
  first_name: Joi.string().min(1),
  last_name: Joi.string()
    .min(1)
    .required(),
  password: Joi.string()
    .regex(/^[\x20-\x7E]+$/)
    .min(8)
    .max(72)
    .required(),
  role: Joi.any().valid(...roles),
  is_active: Joi.boolean().optional()
});
```

Examples:

when a valid role is used no error.

```
const { error, value } = schema.validate({
  first_name: "Magnus",
  last_name: "Carlsen",
  password: "chess/1234",
  role: "staff"
});

console.log(error); //undefined
```

when no role is used no error.

```
const { error, value } = schema.validate({
  first_name: "Magnus",
  last_name: "Carlsen",
  password: "chess/1234"
});

console.log(error); //undefined
```

when a different role is used it gives validation error.

```
const { error, value } = schema.validate({
  first_name: "Magnus",
  last_name: "Carlsen",
  password: "chess/1234",
  role: "unknown"
});

console.log(error); // Error [ValidationError]: "role" must be one of [admin, staff]...
```

Comment: Hi @SuleymanSah, sorry for late reply. Your answer also works. But I went with `role: Joi.string().valid(User.Admin, User.Staff)` according to the Joi changelog @altocumulus mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: `valid(User.Admin, User.Staff)` is the same as `valid(...roles)` with `roles=[User.Admin, User.Staff]`. Which means @SuleymanSah's answer is correct. You may accept it as the correct answer

Comment: not really, because if you declare it as *enum* in *typescript* you cannot spread it as you say, it won't work currently, `roles=[User.Admin, User.Staff]` is an average array of enums.
The original question used this format:
`enum UserRole {
  Admin = 'admin',
  Staff = 'staff'
}`
Of course, it would be better to just use valid(Enum), but this API is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum UserRole {
  Admin = 'admin',
  Staff = 'staff'
}

const validator = {
  create: Joi.object().keys({
    first_name: Joi.string().min(1),
    last_name: Joi.string()
      .min(1)
      .required(),
    password: Joi.string()
      .regex(/^[\x20-\x7E]+$/)
      .min(8)
      .max(72)
      .required(),
    role: Joi.string()
      .valid(UserRole.Admin, UserRole.Staff) // do not use an array
      .optional(),
    is_active: Joi.boolean().optional()
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Joi.string().valid(...Object.values(YourEnum))`.

In your case it would be :

```ts
enum UserRole {
  Admin = 'admin',
  Staff = 'staff'
}

...
role: Joi.string().valid(...Object.values(UserRole));
...
```